# Implementation of FENCE in the RISC-V Rocket processor

Tags: riscv

What does the FENCE instruction do in the Rocket CPU? I tried going through the fpga source but could not find it.

Aside, where is the write buffer implemented? I might get my answer there :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[[Rocket's source code]](https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket) (Rocket is a 5-stage processor).

Instructions that require a `fence`, like `FENCE` or certain atomic operations, will be stalled in the Decode Stage until the cache tells the control logic that a `fence` operation may proceed (i.e., the cache is now "ordered"). The cache does this via the "ordered" signal. The data-cache would not be ordered if, for example, it had an outstanding cache miss it is waiting on.

The best place to look is [ctrl.scala](https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket/blob/master/src/main/scala/ctrl.scala), which contains the instructions and their control signals.  The (non-blocking) data cache's code can be found in [nbdcache.scala](https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/tree/master/src/main/scala/rocket/NBDcache.scala).

I believe the writeback unit governs the writing back of store-data, but this is a very complex, high-performance cache with AMO and ECC support, so do not expect it to match much simpler cache designs where a write-buffer would conceptually be drawn as being between the processor and the cache.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Is there any place where this mechanism is documented?

Since Rocket is an in-order core, I guess there is no speculative execution support. Stalling on fence and atomic instructions seems to be conservative as a whole deal of research has gone to reducing this overhead.

Comment: I would look at the video & slides on Rocket found here (http://riscv.org/workshop-jan2015.html) for an overview. But for this low-level of detail, I'm afraid for now the code is the best documentation. I don't think there's really any research - or really even any point - to accelerating speculatively past fences in a 5-stage processor. The penalty is just too small and the costs too large.